# How do I double the size of an array in C

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic

I have a program that starts with a minimum of 10 responses(int) stored in a dynamic array  but should double in size using a void function if need be .

```
typedef int* Statistician;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Statistician answer;
  answer=(int*)calloc(SIZE,sizeof(int));

  add(answer, &SIZE);
  
}

void add(Statistician answer, int *SIZE){
    answer=(int*)calloc(*SIZE * 2,sizeof(int)); 
}
```

is this the right way to double its size?
I need a little nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619428/increasing-array-size-dynamically-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985106/dynamically-increase-size-of-array-int-in-c

Comment: You are leaking memory, use `realloc` instead.

Comment: @DavidRanieri - not only leaking-memory, but throwing away all original data when the original pointer to the original block containing the data is over-written `:)` Bad juju...

Answer (score 1):

The biggest misunderstanding is you are passing `answer` by-value to `add()` so `add()` receives a copy and any changes to `answer` in `add()` are lost on function return. And since the type is `void` you have no chance of making changes to `answer` seen back in the caller (`main()` here)

To fix the issue, pass the address of `answer` to `add()` so you operate on the original pointer address when you `realloc()` not `calloc()` to double the size, e.g.

```
void add(Statistician *answer, int *SIZE){
    void *tmp = realloc(*answer, *SIZE * 2 * sizeof **answer);
    if (!tmp) {
        perror ("add-realloc-answer");
        return;
    }
    *answer = tmp;
    /* optional - zero new memory mimicking calloc() */
    memset (*answer + *SIZE, 0, *SIZE * sizeof **answer);
    *SIZE *= 2;
}
```

You call add like:

```
    add(&answer, &SIZE);
```

(note, `SIZE` must be a global `int` properly initialized. It should actually be replace in `main()` with `size_t size = SIZE;` at the beginning and then pass a pointer to `size`).

Your confusion is compounded because you **typedeffed** the pointer, see [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). Additionally, in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc`, or `realloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

**Eliminating The `typedef` Of The Pointer**

To keep the levels of pointer indirection apparent it is far easier to avoid the `typedef` of the pointer and simply use `int*` where the type is needed. Making those changes, and changing the use of `SIZE` with a local variable `size` to ensure any local copies passed as parameters don't collide with a global variable. Adding simple routines to fill each integer and validate every integer before/after `add()` is accounted for,  a preferred approach would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 128

int *add (int **answer, size_t *size)
{
    /* always realloc to a temporary pointer, when realloc fails
     * it returns NULL and if you assign to original pointer you
     * create a memory leak with loss of your stored data.
     */
    void *tmp = realloc(*answer, *size * 2 * sizeof **answer);
    if (!tmp) { /* validate every allocation */
        perror ("add-realloc-answer");
        return NULL;
    }
    *answer = tmp;  /* assign reallocated block to pointer */
    /* optional - zero new memory mimicking calloc() */
    memset (*answer + *size, 0, *size * sizeof **answer);
    *size *= 2;     /* update size only on success */
    
    return *answer; /* return pointer indicating success */
}

int main(void) {
    
    int *answer;
    size_t size = SIZE;
    
    answer = calloc(size, sizeof *answer);  /* allocate */
    if (answer == NULL) {                   /* validate */
        perror ("calloc-answer");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)       /* fill memory */
        answer[i] = i;
    
    if (!add(&answer, &size))   /* add and validate return */
        fputs ("realloc failed, using original size.\n", stderr);
    else
        printf ("realloc succeeded -- %zu integers.\n", size);
    
    for (size_t i = size/2; i < size; i++)  /* fill new memory */
        answer[i] = i;
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)       /* validate complete block */
        if (i != (size_t)answer[i])
            fprintf (stderr, "error: answer[%zu] != %d\n", i, answer[i]);
    
    free (answer);      /* free allocated memory */
}
```

**Note:** since `realloc()` can fail, your function needs a way to communicate success or failure back to the caller. Choose a meaningful return type (`int` `0/1` or a pointer `valid address/NULL`, etc...)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/realloc-add
realloc succeeded -- 256 integers.
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/realloc-add
==8594== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==8594== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==8594== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==8594== Command: ./bin/realloc-add
==8594==
realloc succeeded -- 256 integers.
==8594==
==8594== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8594==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8594==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 2,560 bytes allocated
==8594==
==8594== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==8594==
==8594== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8594== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Let me know if you have further questions.